# Yocto: /usr/bin/perf: line 13: exec: perf_4.14: not found

Tags: linux, yocto, perf

I have a beagle bone black which runs a Yocto [distribution](https://tutorialadda.com/yocto/create-linux-image-for-beaglebone-black-using-yocto-build-system) and when executing the perf command I get the following error:

```
# perf
/usr/bin/perf: line 13: exec: perf_4.14: not found
E: linux-perf-4.14 is not installed.
root@beaglebone:~# ls /usr/bin/perf*
/usr/bin/perf
```

Most ressources online suggest to do something along the lines of `sudo apt update` but this is not possible here.

```
~# file /usr/bin/perf
/usr/bin/perf: Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable
root@beaglebone:~# type -a perf
perf is /usr/bin/perf
```

Why exactly am I seeing this error and how could it be fixed?

The `/usr/bin/perf` script is:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
 
# Execute the right version of perf for the current kernel.
# Remove flavour or custom suffix and fix number of version components to 2.
version="$(uname -r)"
version="${version%%-*}"
case "$version" in
    *.*.*)
        version="${version%.*}"
        ;;
esac
shopt -s execfail
exec "perf_$version" "$@"
 
# Not found? Tell the user which package to install.
case "$version" in
    3.* | 4.0 | 4.0.*)
        package=linux-tools-$version
        ;;
    *)
        package=linux-perf-$version
        ;;
esac
echo >&2 "E: $package is not installed."
exit 1
```

Line 14 is

```
exec "perf_$version" "$@"
```

Comment: What does `type perf` say?

Comment: And `file /usr/bin/perf`

Comment: @Barmar: `type -a perf` might be more useful, to see if there are any other `perf` executables other than the one that didn't work.  (BTW, on my Arch GNU/Linux system, `/usr/bin/perf` is an ELF binary, not a script with line numbers that execs something else.  So this problem is probably specific to how Yocto packages `perf`.)

Comment: @Barmar updated my post

Comment: @PeterCordes updated my post

Comment: So it's a shell script that's looking for something named `perf_4.14`, but that's not installed. You need to install it.

Comment: And since it's a shell script, you should be able to read it and figure out what it's trying to do and why.

Comment: @Barmar that doesn't give much info. THis is the content of the script...: https://pastebin.com/UJY6L2gb What is the proper way of intstalling this? As stated using apt does not work on yocto

What are your thoughts?

Comment: @PeterCordes ^^

Comment: You need to install `linux-perf-4.14` as it says.

Comment: As mentioned from @barmar,seems to be a script, can you cat it?

Comment: @Paiusco They put a link to it in a comment. I copied the code to the question.

Comment: Do you have any perf binary on the system? `find / - name "*perf*" `